# Python: Computing the distance between two point coordinates using two columns

Tags: python, loops, math, haversine

I would like to compute the distance between two coordinates. I know I can compute the haversine distance between two points. However, I was wondering if there is an easier way of doing it instead of creating a loop using the formula iterating over the entire columns (also getting errors in the loop).

Here's some data for the example

```
# Random values for the duration from one point to another
random_values = random.sample(range(2,20), 8)
random_values

# Creating arrays for the coordinates
lat_coor = [11.923855, 11.923862, 11.923851, 11.923847, 11.923865, 11.923841, 11.923860, 11.923846]
lon_coor = [57.723843, 57.723831, 57.723839, 57.723831, 57.723827, 57.723831, 57.723835, 57.723827]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'duration': random_values,
     'latitude': lat_coor,
     'longitude': lon_coor
    })

df

    duration    latitude    longitude
0   5           11.923855   57.723843
1   2           11.923862   57.723831
2   10          11.923851   57.723839
3   19         11.923847    57.723831
4   16         11.923865    57.723827
5   4          11.923841    57.723831
6   13         11.923860    57.723835
7   3          11.923846    57.723827
```

To compute the distance this is what I've attempted:

```
# Looping over each row to compute the Haversine distance between two points
# Earth's radius (in m)
R = 6373.0 * 1000

lat = df["latitude"]
lon = df["longitude"]


for i in lat:
    lat1 = lat[i]
    lat2 = lat[i+1]
    
    for j in lon:
        lon1 = lon[i]
        lon2 = lon[i+1]
        
        dlon = lon2 - lon1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1
        
        # Haversine formula
        a = math.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon / 2)**2
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
        distance = R * c
        
        print(distance) # in m
```

However, this is the error I get:
[image]

The two points to compute the distance should be taken from the same column.

**first distance value:**

11.923855 57.723843 (point1/observation1)

11.923862 57.723831 (point2/observation2)

**second distance value:**

11.923862 57.723831 (point1/observation2)

11.923851 57.723839(point2/observation3)

**third distance value:**

11.923851 57.723839(point1/observation3)

11.923847 57.723831 (point1/observation4)

... (and so on)

Comment: You need two points (lat1, lon1) and (lat2, lon2) to compute the distance. Each row in your data frame only has one point. Can you specify with which other point the distance should be computed?

Comment: I've edited the question to make this part clearer. They should come from the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first you can create a dataframe that combine each measurement with the previous one:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.add_suffix('_pre').shift(), df], axis=1)
df2
```

This outputs:

```
    duration_pre    latitude_pre    longitude_pre   duration    latitude    longitude
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     5   11.923855   57.723843
1   5.0     11.923855   57.723843   2   11.923862   57.723831
2   2.0     11.923862   57.723831   10  11.923851   57.723839
…
```

Then create a `haversine` function and apply it to the rows:

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    import math
    R = 6373.0 * 1000
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = math.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon / 2)**2
    return R *2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))

df2.apply(lambda x: haversine(x['latitude_pre'], x['longitude_pre'], x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis=1)
```

which computes for each row the distance with the previous row (first one is thus NaN).

```
0           NaN
1     75.754755
2     81.120210
3     48.123604
…
```

And, if you want to include a new column in the original dataframe in one line:

```
df['distance'] = pd.concat([df.add_suffix('_pre').shift(), df], axis=1).apply(lambda x: haversine(x['latitude_pre'], x['longitude_pre'], x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  duration  latitude    longitude   distance
0   5   11.923855   57.723843   NaN
1   2   11.923862   57.723831   75.754755
2   10  11.923851   57.723839   81.120210
3   19  11.923847   57.723831   48.123604
4   16  11.923865   57.723827   116.515304
5   4   11.923841   57.723831   154.307571
6   13  11.923860   57.723835   122.794838
7   3   11.923846   57.723827   98.115312
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you want to get the pairwise haversine distance between all points in your df. Here's how this could be done:

**Be careful when using this approach with a lot of points as it generates a lot of columns quickly**

#### Setup

```py
import random 
random_values = random.sample(range(2,20), 8)
random_values

# Creating arrays for the coordinates
lat_coor = [11.923855, 11.923862, 11.923851, 11.923847, 11.923865, 11.923841, 11.923860, 11.923846]
lon_coor = [57.723843, 57.723831, 57.723839, 57.723831, 57.723827, 57.723831, 57.723835, 57.723827]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'duration': random_values,
     'latitude': lat_coor,
     'longitude': lon_coor
    })
```

#### Get radians

```py
import math
df['lat_rad'] = df.latitude.apply(math.radians)
df['long_rad'] = df.latitude.apply(math.radians)
```

#### Calculate pairwise distances

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances

for idx_from, from_point in df.iterrows():
    for idx_to, to_point in df.iterrows():
            column_name = f"Distance_to_point_{idx_from}"
            haversine_matrix = haversine_distances([[from_point.lat_rad, from_point.long_rad], [to_point.lat_rad, to_point.long_rad]])
            point_distance = haversine_matrix[0][1] * 6371000/1000
            df.loc[idx_to, column_name] = point_distance
df

    duration    latitude    longitude   lat_rad long_rad    Distance_to_point_0 Distance_to_point_1 Distance_to_point_2 Distance_to_point_3 Distance_to_point_4 Distance_to_point_5 Distance_to_point_6 Distance_to_point_7
0   3   11.923855   57.723843   0.20811052928038845 0.20811052928038845 0.0 0.0010889626934743966   0.0006222644021223135   0.001244528808978787    0.0015556609862946524   0.002177925427923575    0.000777830496776312    0.0014000949117650525
1   13  11.923862   57.723831   0.2081106514534361  0.2081106514534361  0.0010889626934743966   0.0 0.0017112270955967099   0.002333491502453183    0.0004666982928202561   0.00326688812139797 0.00031113219669808446  0.0024890576052394482
2   14  11.923851   57.723839   0.2081104594672184  0.2081104594672184  0.0006222644021223135   0.0017112270955967099   0.0 0.0006222644068564735   0.002177925388416966    0.0015556610258012616   0.0014000948988986254   0.0007778305096427389
3   4   11.923847   57.723831   0.20811038965404832 0.20811038965404832 0.001244528808978787    0.002333491502453183    0.0006222644068564735   0.0 0.0028001897952734385   0.0009333966189447881   0.002022359305755099    0.0001555661027862654
4   5   11.923865   57.723827   0.20811070381331365 0.20811070381331365 0.0015556609862946524   0.0004666982928202561   0.002177925388416966    0.0028001897952734385   0.0 0.003733586414218225    0.0007778304895183407   0.002955755898059704
5   7   11.923841   57.723831   0.20811028493429318 0.20811028493429318 0.002177925427923575    0.00326688812139797 0.0015556610258012616   0.0009333966189447881   0.003733586414218225    0.0 0.002955755924699886    0.0007778305161585227
6   9   11.92386    57.723835   0.20811061654685106 0.20811061654685106 0.000777830496776312    0.00031113219669808446  0.0014000948988986254   0.002022359305755099    0.0007778304895183407   0.002955755924699886    0.0 0.002177925408541364
7   8   11.923846   57.723827   0.20811037220075576 0.20811037220075576 0.0014000949117650525   0.0024890576052394482   0.0007778305096427389   0.0001555661027862654   0.002955755898059704    0.0007778305161585227   0.002177925408541364    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the index versus the values themselves, so you are getting a key error because there is no lat[i] (e.g., lat[11.923855]) in your example.  After fixing i to be the index, your code would go beyond the last row of lat and lon with your [i+1].  Since you want to compare each row to the previous row, how about starting at index 1 and looking back by 1, then you won't go out of range.  This edited version of your code does not crash:

```
for i in range(1, len(lat)):
    lat1 = lat[i - 1]
    lat2 = lat[i]

    for j in range(1, len(lon)):
        lon1 = lon[i - 1]
        lon2 = lon[i]

        dlon = lon2 - lon1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1

        # Haversine formula
        a = math.sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
        distance = R * c

        print(distance)  # in m
```